# flutter linear gradient color issue

Tags: flutter, linear-gradients

in `flutter linear gradient color`, I couldn't figure out what I did, how do I catch the softness of the color transitions? this problem only exists in android emulator, there is no problem in ios simulator.

```
gradient: new LinearGradient(
          colors: [Color(0xFF0f1129), Color(0xFF213259)],
          begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          end: Alignment.topCenter,
          stops: [0.0, 1.0],`enter code here`
          tileMode: TileMode.clamp),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in your `main()` to make it softer,

```
void main(){
  Paint.enableDithering = true;
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution that worked for me was going to the emulator settings. In Settings, go to the Advanced tab and change the default OpenGL ES renderer to SwiftShader and also change the OpenGL ES API Level to Renderer Maximum.

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlcIx.png)